# Distinguish response.sendRedirect() from direct browser get

Tags: url, servlets, redirect, http-headers

I have a scenario which I do `response.sendRedirect()` from one server to another. In the second server it has a form and do a form submit to first server back.

(Actual scenario is a SAML login flow where first server is an Identity Provider and the second server is the one hosting the login page.)

My problem is, I don't want to user to bookmark the login page and come to the login page directly. For example, if the user directly come to the login page after a week, it have invalid URL parameters which expired in the server 1 (IdP).

Is there way to distinguish a direct GET done by user, from the redirection done by the server 1.

Setting `attributes`, `Headers` would did not worked(which is expected). And since these are on two servers, I cannot use `forward()` as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, There is no way Redirect supports POST. The only way possible is let the first servlet act as proxy and make the request to the other server.

Comment: post redirect with 307 would be a option?